# Creasing in new Gore-Tex boots: reduced longevity?

Tags: boots, gore-tex

I just got a pair of Scarpa Terra GTX's which I really like. However the only option the store had are ones that have clearly been worn a few times around the store leading to some creasing and fading. The soles look pretty new, certainly they don't look like anyone has taken a rock to the arch of the foot, and the inside looks pretty pristine.

My question is: does this level (see pictures) of creasing and 'wear' constitute any degradation in longevity or is it purely cosmetic? They were on sale and their last pair in this size so room for haggling was pretty slim.

For the same price I can get these boots, hopefully brand new, from interstate. This is a bit of a pain in case i want to return for whatever reason, but relatively easy so I am considering taking a punt on some brand new ones and returning these, but if wiser folk than I think i'm making a mountain out of molehills I won't bother.

I've already applied a bit of wax and that fixed the fading and some scuffs but the creases remain. I know leather is pretty robust but i also know that Gore-Tex doesn't last forever and naively i feel like eventually enough bending and creasing will reduce the life of that waterproof lining.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary difference this will make is that they'll be just a little easier to "walk in" as some of the work has been done for you already. At the point where they're truly comfortable they'll be a lot more creased than that, and it's only after that point that you'll really be able to put the miles on them.

It's cosmetic, don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks! As it turns out it's a bit of a moot point as after stomping around the house in them for a few days i've decided they're too narrow, but this is good information for future purchases so I appreciate it nonetheless.